# LVM Expand RAID1 with Asymmetric Segments Across 3 Heterogeneous Disks

Tags: raid, storage, lvm, software-raid, raid1

I have 3 disks: one 1TB drive (A1), one 2TB drive (A2), and one 3TB drive (B). Currently, A2 has data on it in one LV that is 1.6TB in size. A1, A2, and B are PVs, in a volume group MyVG. I desire a setup like:

```
A* = RAID0-linear(A1 + A2)
MyNewLV = RAID1(A*, B)
```

However, I've struggled to figure out how to get LVM to do this.

My first idea was to expand the current LV (on A2) to raid1 (A2 and B), then extend it onto A1, but the lvextend complained about insufficient extents on the A side.

<strike>My next idea was to create 1.1TiB (ensuring it was over multiple disks already), then do a cycle of move data-lvreduce-lvextend. So I tried:</strike>

```
$ lvcreate --type raid1 -m 1 --raidintegrity y  -L 1.1TiB -n MyNewLV MyVG
```

But this too complained about insufficient extents.

*Edit: That idea seems to work now (unsure what I did the first time), but it isn't ideal from a copying POV, so the question still remains*

*Edit2: That command actually created some sort of striped volume*

How can I create this weirdly-shaped RAID1 volume without moving the data on A2 around too much?

I don't care about striping across A1 and A2